# Where are PHP files created by BigCommerce Stencil CLI stored?

Tags: bigcommerce

BigCommerce has a node.js app which allows you to do Stencil development locally.  Part of the simulation it gives you is URLs like `http://localhost:3000/cart.php` for the shopping cart page.  I'd like to understand how this is done and where the cart.php file could be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .php files are not available for editing; these URLs are merely proxied from BigCommerce servers when you're using the CLI.

Essentially, stencil-CLI gets the data from the cart page which is then compiled via node into the HTML output (using your local template).

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, accessing php portions of BigCommerce to post changes is not really possible. It's the same for checkout.php as well. You'll have to post changes via scss files or via using handlebars and/or js-jquery.

Here's a similar question from BC forum:
https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00003zd4GSSAY/editing-a-php-page